# knockout js dropdownlist group image

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

i would like to put group label with image there, how could i achieve this?

for example this image
[image]

here i want to set Images at Europe, NorthAmercia,SouthAmerica Groups

code is here,

```
<select data-bind="foreach: groups, value: selectedOption">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: label}, foreach: children">
        <option data-bind="text: label, option: $data"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>


<hr />
```

more code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/aCS7D/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have things like images in your options, you would likely want to look at using a plugin like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).  Look at the "Templating" example on that doc page which includes an example with images.

Comment: but i need images at groupnames, i am not able to find example there, and i really dont like to use plugin :) , can't we put image and lable in optgroup?

Comment: here is a quick sample of formatting the optgroup: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ws4Mq/